# Server-side rendering for a specific selection

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Let's say my app is a list of many items. There's a lot of items so I don't want to include all the items in the redux state.

When a user visits me at myapp.com/item/:itemId, I want to display the selected item. Currently I make an api call in componentDidMount to fetch the item and store the response in myReduxState.selectedItem. However, this shows the user and unfinished page until the api call finishes.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Have you read about server rendering with redux? http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: You will have to fetch that data before you compile the HTML. You should also include something in the redux state that indicates whether or not data needs to be fetch. That way the client-side can check that before making the ajax call in componentDidMount.

Comment: If you want it to be truly server-side rendered, you'll have to move the fetch to componentWillMount, which gets called on both the server and client (componentDidMount is only called on the client). You will also need to use a isomorphic/universal fetch library like isomorphic-fetch or axios or superagent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making the creating the state on the server side. I get the itemId from the url in my express route and get the details of the specific item. I use this to create the state and pass it to the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I tend to follow is to have a state of `fetching` being tracked in the redux state. Once the api resolves you just make sure the state is set correctly and then in your render methods use that to determine what you are rendering.

```
render() {
 if (this.state.fetching) { 

  return <div> // put whatever you want here, maybe a loading component?</div>

 }

 return ( 
   // put the regular content you would put for when the api call finishes and have the data you need
 )
}
```